# How to handle promise.all rejecting one promise out of three promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, promise.all

I have a unique situation where 2 promises are running together in Promise.all.
but one of the promise is taking long time and hence I am not getting any result.
Other promise are getting resolved except one.
I want to reject the promise taking long time (eg: if more than 60 sec) with an error message so that I can get a response from Promise.all.

e.g::

```
const [client1Prices, client2Prices] = await Promise.all([
      this.client1.getSimulationPrices({
        hourPay: journey.hourPay,
        jobType: journey.jobType,
        salary: journey.salary,
        weeklyHours: journey.weeklyHours,
      }),
      this.client2.getSimulationPrices({   // takes more than 60 sec and i want to reject this promise
        hourPay: journey.hourPay,
        jobType: journey.jobType,
        salary: journey.salary,
        weeklyHours: journey.weeklyHours,
      })
    ]);
```

this.client2.getSimulationPrices is taking a lot of time to resolve and hence Promise.all is not giving me any result. I want to reject this in 60 second such thatI can get response from Promise.all.

Please suggest how can this situation be handled ?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to access the result from the first promise if the second rejects?

Comment: Yeah I am expecting the result from first promise and some error message from second promise.

Comment: with `Promise.all()` if one rejects they all reject. (in essence)

Comment: Thats why I want to handle the promise that is taking long time with some form of error message if it takes more time so that I can continue doing further tasks.

Comment: My approach is failing. What could be the best solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `Promise.allSettled()`

It return ar array of objects promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected.

Each objects in the array describes the outcome of each promise.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'Prmoise 2'));
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 200, 'Promise 3'));

const promise4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 200, 'Promise 4'));

const promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4];

Promise.allSettled(promises).
then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)));

// expected output:

// "fulfilled"
// "rejected"
// "fulfilled"
// "rejected"
```

#### More info

[Promise.allSettled() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

---

*All major browsers support it. So you do not need to use any external library or even polyfills.*

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Promise.allSettled()`. Unlike `Promise.all()` it would not thrown an error if any of the promises fails. Instead the result is an object that is either:

```
{
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: return_value
}
```

if there was no error or:

```
{
    status: 'rejected',
    reason: error_message
}
```

if there was an error.

MDN says this is supported from node 12.9.0 and above. If you need it in an environment that does not have it there is a pure-js implementation on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: This does not address the timeout concern.  If the promise takes longer than 60sec (success or fail), `Promise.allSettled()` will still wait too long to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using observables as this is a bit easier to handle, however, you can still do this with promises.

You'll want to use [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

The `Promise.race()` method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

```js
const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('TIMEOUT'), 60000));
});
const [client1Prices, client2Prices] = await Promise.all([
      this.client1.getSimulationPrices({
        hourPay: journey.hourPay,
        jobType: journey.jobType,
        salary: journey.salary,
        weeklyHours: journey.weeklyHours,
      }),
      Promise.race([timeoutPromise, this.client2.getSimulationPrices({
        hourPay: journey.hourPay,
        jobType: journey.jobType,
        salary: journey.salary,
        weeklyHours: journey.weeklyHours,
      })])
    ]);
```

You are guaranteed to have `client2Prices` return in 60sec or less. You can check the value to determine if it timed out or if it succeeded. If you wanted to swallow the timeout error (not have `Promise.all()` fail, you can either make the timeout `resolve` (instead of `reject`), or switch to use `Promise.allSettled()`

Answer (score 0):

An excellent library for Promises is [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/timeout.html).
It has a `timeout` function that would prove useful here.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const [client1Prices, client2Prices] = await Promise.allSettled([
      this.client1.getSimulationPrices(...).timeout(60000),
      this.client2.getSimulationPrices(...).timeout(60000)
    ]);
```